# How to rewrite with wildcards in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I rewrite this:

```
www.mydomain.com/directoryname/(wildcard)
```

to this:

```
www.myotherdomain.com/directoryname/(wildcard)
```

I have many subdirectories and files on the `"myotherdomain.com` domain name, and I need those to be accessible via the `mydomain.com` wildcard. I assume I will need to use htaccess to achieve this, but have not bee able to figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in the document root of the `www.mydomain.com` site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^directoryname/(.*)$ http://www.myotherdomain.com/directoryname/$1 [L,R]
```

That will redirect the browser, which means the address in the URL changes. If you don't want it to change, then you need to have mod_proxy loaded, and change the `R` to a `P`. If mod_proxy isn't loaded, then the `P` flag won't work.

Comment: Hmmm, almost! That redirects www.mydomain.com/directoryname/blahblahblah to www.myotherdomain.com/directoryname, but I need it to redirect to www.myotherdomain.com/directoryname/blahblahblah